How can I run a Powershell command from a folder?
I have no experience with cmd and Powershell so I don't know exactly what my options are, so it doesn't have to necessarily be from a folder.
I have a folder whose files I need to batch rename. I've been doing this by going to the folder, opening Powershell, and then pasting the command and running it.
But this is something that I'll be doing twice a week, with the renamed files being deleted after use, and be replaced by not-yet renamed files where I'll then run the script again, and so forth. Because it's the exact same command that needs to be called from the same folder, I'm wondering if there's a less cumbersome way to do it, especially as my coworkers have an even lesser grasp of Powershell than I do.
The "ideal" case would be to store the Powershell command in the folder in question as an executable file that can be run by double-clicking, so that when the new, un-renamed files were added to the folder the user would just need to double-click on the script file in the already opened folder to run it, but from my research I think this is more of a complicated workaround than anything else.


Create a powershell script. The first command/cmdlet will be go to that folder: cd c:\path\to\your\folder.
Then, the other  powershell commands to rename the files. Save the script as ps1 file.
You can run the file directly or right-click and select Run with Powershell


@ReddyLutonadio I can save the script as a .ps1 file, but running it only opens it on Notepad, which is the common issue with the Windows security measures.

@maliebina  Right-Click on the file > select Run With PowerShell

Create a shortcut and change the target as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137272/11443568 .

Unfortunately both the shortcut and right-clicking wield the same result, the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. I'm trying to find a solution for that

Change the execution policy to Bypass or RemoteSigned. Something like powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

I came across that solution as well, but I'm not sure how to apply this to my case. I have my ps1 file as a shortcut, so where exactly would I insert the bypass for this specific file?

Check this answer and its comments.
